# Pin add constraint in Xcode auto enlarges my frame rectangle

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In Xcode 8.3.3 I have an image view.  In this image view I have an image that is 245 x 130.  Whenever I click on add new constraint and select the 
"Add constraint"

[image]

the frame rectangle enlarges.

[image]

Even if I reset the rectangle to it's original size when I run the simulator the image is enlarged out of proportion.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Set `clipToBounds` = true

Comment: First, do you know the actual reason why you are going to use those `pins`? If not, don't use the pins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your UIImageView is missing constraints. You can tell by the red frame edges on the View. This is because you only added one constraint to the top, which is not enough information for the layout engine to correctly render the view. InterfaceBuilder will give you suggestions on how to fix this issue.
If you have a fixed size image, just add constraints for width and height and a constraint that defines the position on the x-axis (e.g. center in superview).